# CUDA memory issues in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, bert-language-model

I'm trying to fine tune BERT for a classification task in Google Colab, and I often get the `CUDA out of memory` error. But this is a bit strange:

1. If I run my training loop with batch size, say, 20 it might initially be okay for a while. Then suppose I stop the code and try again, it'll give me CUDA memory issues. Even if I reduce the batch size to 1, it gives me the same error. However, if I restart runtime (or factory restart), it runs fine. What causes memory issues over multiple runs? I don't think I'm storing anything, so the only thing which should matter is batch size.
2. My Colab session often crashes due to RAM after multiple runs, but works okay for a bit after restarting runtime.

Here is the code I'm using for training. The class `Model` is  my model, which consists of pre-trained BERT (Huggingface transformers library) and a few layers on top.

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = Model().to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = 3e-4) 
criterion = nn.BCELoss().to(device)

batch_size = 32
train_data_loader = utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size = batch_size) #data is subclass of torch.utils.data.Dataset

def train(n_epochs): 
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs): 
        total_loss = 0
        for embeddings, labels in train_data_loader: 
            labels = (labels.double()).to(device)
            input_ids = (embeddings['input_ids'].squeeze(1)).to(device)
            attention_mask = (embeddings['attention_mask'].squeeze(1)).to(device)
            output = model(input_ids, attention_mask)
            loss = criterion(output, labels)
            total_loss += loss.item()
            model.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        
        print(f'epoch {epoch+1}, total loss = {total_loss}')

total_epochs = 10
train(total_epochs)
```

Is there anything wrong or inefficient about my training loop causing the error?

Comment: It's possible that Python's garbage collector is simply not running often enough. Maybe try running `gc.collect` after every epoch, and see if it works. Maybe also try running the model on your CPU and see when the RAM usage increases?

Comment: @SagarPatil RAM increases like crazy on the forward pass through the BERT (by like 8GB) which shouldn't be happening. I'm also using a small batch size, 32 (on CPU). Do you know what might be going wrong?

Comment: The BERT model is just that big, is what I'm guessing. The batch size only affects the size of the activation matrices, and not the weights. NLP models, especially state of the art ones, have a very high parameter count. A lot of times, it's not feasible to train(or even inference) these models unless you have a high VRAM GPU such as the 1080 Ti. There isn't really an easy way around this.